# Mutex and order of execution

Tags: c, unix, posix, mutex

First of all I am still new to posix programming and still understanding basic concepts.  It is still not very clear for me how do `pthread_mutex_lock`
`pthread_mutex_unlock` do work.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#inlcude <stdio.h>
pthread_mutex_t_mtx;
void* routine(void* i){
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < 1000000; ++j){
         pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
         printf("Inside thread %d\n", i);
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t th[3];
   int i;
   pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, NULL);
   for(i = 1; i <= 2; ++i)
   {
      if(pthread_create(th + i, NULL, routine, i){
           perror(NULL);  return 1;
      }
   }

   for(i = 1; i <=2; ++i)
        pthread_join(th[i], NULL);

   return 0;
}
```

What should be the correct output of the above program ? I think that because of the lock and unlock of the mutex there would be 2000000 iterations, but it is not very clear for me the order that they are done in. Does the first thread execute the first 1000000 steps of the for? Does it even execute the first one of the 20000000 ? Or does this happen by a more chaotic order?

Comment: Given `void *i`, `printf("Inside thread %d\n", i);` is wrong.  The proper format specifier for a `void *` is `%p`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the mutex is a global one, you will get 2000000 messages, with 1000000 from each thread. The order of those is random, however they will not interfere each other as each print is protected by the mutex

EDIT: I just noticed, that you are joining before creating the next thread. Therfore first there will be all messages of the first, then of the second thread. In this case the mutex has no effect at all. The reason for the ordering is simply that you will not have more then one worker-thread running at the same time.

Comment: What do you mean by  they will not interfere each other?

Comment: If you would call printf from two threads at the same time, lets say print("AA") and printf("BB"), then you could get the output `ABAB` as both threads could write to the terminal simoultainusly. This race-condition can be prevent by a mutex. However in your case there will only be one thread at a time running (besides the main thread)

Comment: That ```pthread_join``` was accidental.  I have one more question. Won't the variable ```j``` in the iterations be affected from the two threads modifying it simultaneously?

Comment: No, as the variable is local in each thread (Each thread has its own copy). If it would be a global variable, then yes, you would have a race condition.

Comment: But don't threads share the same 'memory space'? Or does that apply only to global variables? Sorry if the question is dumb but I really want to understand...

Comment: Yes this applies to the global variables and heap allocated objects. But each thread has its own stack. And all local variables are allocated on the stack when entering the function (if you are not using malloc etc.) and therefore each thread has its own copy of the `j` variable

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you!